# Key type is a duplicate in Composer

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I'm using Amazon S3 to version some of my premium WordPress plugins.

I require them using Composer, but I'm getting a warning `Key type is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line XX`.

This is the repository part of my `composer.json`. I've tried a few different versions already but I'm not sure what to replace `packages` with instead. The dependencies are downloading fine, but I like to get rid of this error as the deployment pipeline is suffering when it's checking for issues.

```
"repositories": [{
  "type": "composer",
  "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
},
{
  "type": "composer",
  "url": "https://composer.deliciousbrains.com/xxx"
},
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "2.6.1",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx_2.6.1.zip"
    }
  },
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "2.0.1",
    "type": "wordpress-theme",
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx.zip"
    }
  }
}
]
```

Comment: so you have wrong nesting. syntax highlight here on SO make it's easier to catch up

Comment: Added syntax, didn't make a difference. I also think it's already being [detected](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Could you be more clear on my nesting?

Comment: 10th and 20th(as well as 11th and 21st) lines. they are on the same level and refer to the same key. I believe you accidentally merged 2 separated objects by dropping 2 braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"repositories": [{ 
    "type": "composer", 
    "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
}, {
    "type": "composer", 
    "url": "https://composer.deliciousbrains.com/xxx" 
}, {
    "type": "package", 
    "package": { 
        "name": "xxx", 
        "version": "2.6.1", 
        "type": "wordpress-plugin", 
        "dist": { 
            "type": "zip", 
            "url": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx_2.6.1.zip"
        }
    }
}, {
    "type": "package", 
    "package": { 
        "name": "xxx", 
        "version": "2.0.1", 
        "type": "wordpress-theme", 
        "dist": { 
            "type": "zip", 
            "url": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx.zip" 
        }
    }
}]
```

2 braces were skipped so sibling objects became merged into one

Comment: When I try this, my Atom is showing syntax errors. (I made an edit in my post, I think we posted at the same time). (**Edit:** I was wrong, sorry - that solved the error. Thanks a lot, upvoted).